# Forming Django queryset for one-to-many relation

Tags: python, django, performance, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a Django model defining a photo:

```
class Pic(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_pic_to_location, storage=OverwriteStorage())
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    upload_time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

And another defining a message the above photo can be sent as:

```
class PicMessage(models.Model):
    which_pic = models.ForeignKey(Pic)
    sending_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I.e. same pic can be sent as a different message multiple times. What's the most efficient way to find the **most recent** `PicMessage` sent by a given `user`?

---

I'm trying this: `PicMessage.objects.filter(which_pic__in=Pic.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)).latest('sending_time')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PicMessage.objects.filter(which_pic__owner=user).order_by('-sending_time').first()
```

Comment: Quick question: would doing `latest('sending_time')` be equivalent performance-wise to doing `order_by('-sending_time').first()`?

Comment: I believe they result in the same sql, if you are worried about fine tuning db performance you need to enable sql log and then use EXPLAIN sql syntax to see if your db indexes are being used by these queries etc. Your solution from the question translates to 2 simple sql queries, mine translates to single but joined. Which one runs faster on your specific data needs to be analyzed.